# Loop to remove columns with NAs by row and run function (do this for each row)

Tags: r, loops, na, vegan

I am running the function diversity in the package vegan but my dataset contains many NAs. The function calculates diversity by row (i.e., plot) but will return NAs if that row has NAs. I looked but couldn't find a solution for NAs using this function. The only thing (maybe) that would solve this problem is removing the columns with NAs each time I run the function, but doing this by hand will take forever. I can't simply remove all NAs from my dataset because this will also remove an entire row and I have some columns with data.

How can I loop to remove columns with NAs by row, run function, store diversity output, and then do the same for the next row until the last row?

dataset example:

```
|species1|species2|species3|species4|species5|species6|species7|species8|
|________|________|________|________|________|________|________|________|
|NA      |90      |75      |NA      |NA      |NA      |NA      |60      |
|90      |NA      |75      |NA      |90      |NA      |90      |60      |
|NA      |NA      |NA      |NA      |NA      |NA      |NA      |33      |
|60      |90      |75      |NA      |30      |NA      |NA      |46      |
|NA      |90      |75      |NA      |NA      |NA      |NA      |NA      |
```

And the diversity function:

```
library("vegan")
diversity(dataset, "invsimpson")
```

Any help is much appreciate. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your dataset is a species x site matrix? i.e. rows are sites/samples, and columns are species?

If so, it is normal to have zeroes to indicate a species was not detected at that site, rather than "NA". I understand that just because you did not detect a species, does not mean it wasn't there, but most analyses of ecological community data take that into account.